# select oracle union and union all did not display the department name name

Tags: oracle

I have used union all to get 2 data from 2 tables but it did not display the department name

```
select employees.department_id,employees.last_name   
  from employees
union all
select departments.department_id ,departments.department_name   
  from departments;
```

Answer (score 1):

Department name *is* displayed (unless that column is `NULL`; I presume it is not), but there's no "department name" column heading.

If that's what bothers you, well, that's how it goes - the result displays column headings belonging to the first `select` statement in that union.

For example:

```
SQL> select 'nghiant' your_name from dual        --> first SELECT statement; YOUR_NAME
  2  union all
  3  select 'littlef' my_name   from dual;

YOUR_NAME               --> see? YOUR_NAME; there's no MY_NAME 
----------
nghiant
littlef

SQL>
```

Comment: To add to this, you probably want a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) statement instead of a UNION.